# How can i prevent the use of self signed certificate?

Tags: android

I want to prevent the Man in the Middle attack for my application. If the third party installs the self signed certificate and access my network. So i just want to prevent the http call made from the self signed certificate on client side(In Android Code).

Any response would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you target SDK 24 or higher it's more difficult to sniff SSL traffic because of this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html

> User-added CAs
>
> Protection of all application data is a key goal of the Android
>   application sandbox. Android Nougat changes how applications interact
>   with user- and admin-supplied CAs. By default, apps that target API
>   level 24 will—by design—not honor such CAs unless the app explicitly
>   opts in. This safe-by-default setting reduces application attack
>   surface and encourages consistent handling of network and file-based
>   application data.

If your `targetSdkVersion` of your APK is 24 or higher it's no more possible to sniff HTTPS traffic with a self-signed certificate because Android OS security rules does trust self-signed certificate no more.

So, for example, what is described here http://www.versionestabile.it/blog/ios-simulator-and-android-emulator-http-proxy/ is not possible if you target API 24 or higher.

The best way is to use "pinning". But that give you more maintenance work.

> Normally, an app trusts all pre-installed CAs. If any of these CAs
>   were to issue a fraudulent certificate, the app would be at risk from
>   a man-in-the-middle attack. Some apps choose to limit the set of
>   certificates they accept by either limiting the set of CAs they trust
>   or by certificate pinning.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CertificatePinning

With certificate pinning you tell your Android APK to just trust the certificates of witch you put the public key SHA in your `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <pin-set expiration="2018-01-01">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=</pin>
            <!-- backup pin -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">fwza0LRMXouZHRC8Ei+4PyuldPDcf3UKgO/04cDM1oE=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

So you can put only your server certificates and any other, still valide, certificates are not trusted.

Note: you must add this in your manifest file in order to use the network config file:

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Anyway there are also some "reverse engineering" techniques that one could use in order to sniff your traffic. Look at this: https://techblog.mediaservice.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/HackInBo-2017-Winter-Edition-Federico-Dotta-Advanced-mobile-penetration-testing-with-Brida-141017.pdf